# trying to check if condition inside a for loop in scala getting compilation error in scala. illegal start of simple expression

Tags: scala, playframework

my code looks like below.

```
<Tr>
@for (r <- addressChangeList) {
@for (rl <- requestList) {
  @if (@r.getRequest_reqnbr() == @rl.getRequestNumber()) { <td>@rl.getRequestNumber() </td> } else { 
      <td> No request found</td>}
     }
  }
</tr>
```

giving me compilation error:

> illegal start of simple expression

I am new to Scala so please help me also how to break the loop if condition matched.

Comment: Could you please provide the whole code? I see you have one extra `}`.

Comment: yes that was by mistake. updated the code. also help me how to break and come out from the loop once the condition satisfies.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the use of `@`: you only use `@` at the start of an expression or block. From your code, this line:

```
@if (@r.getRequest_reqnbr() == @rl.getRequestNumber()) { <td>@rl.getRequestNumber() </td> } else {
```

should be

```
@if (r.getRequest_reqnbr() == rl.getRequestNumber()) { <td>rl.getRequestNumber() </td> } else {
```